# How to convert Arabic text from PyQt4 to UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, encode, arabic

I made a Python 2 GUI application with PyQt4 that has two entries. The first takes the file name, and the second takes the text to write in the file.

I want to enter Arabic text in both of them, so I wrote this function:

```
def makefile(self):
    self.name_file=str(self.lineEdit.text()).decode("utf-8")
    self.string=str(self.lineEdit_2.text()).decode("utf-8")
    file=open(self.name_file,"w")
    file.write(self.string)
    file.close()
```

When I enter English letters it works fine, but when I enter Arabic I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: where are you initializing `self.lineEdit`? What version of Python are you using? Would hope 3 but thought all strings were unicode by default so not sure

Comment: `str(self.lineEdit.text()).decode("utf-8")` seems wrong. `str()` is normally intended for representing something for debug purposes. Also why should you need to decode it, if it's already a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing code to convert from your unicode to UTF-8, you wrote code to convert from UTF-8 to unicode. That's what you're getting errors.

`decode("utf-8")` means

> Take a UTF-8 encoded binary `str` and convert to  a `unicode` string.

Conversely, `encode("utf-8")` means

> take a `unicode` string and encode into a binary `str` using UTF-8.

It looks like you're trying to encode text as UTF-8, so you can write it to your file in UTF-8 encoding. So you should use be using `encode()` instead of `decode()`.

Also, you're taking your `QString` value, which is in unicode, and calling `str()` on it. This attempts to change it to a binary `str` using ASCII, which doesn't work for your Arabic text, and causes the exception you're seeing. And it's not what you wanted to do, anyway—you wanted to use UTF-8, not ASCII. So don't convert it to a binary `str`, convert it to a `unicode` object with `unicode()`.

So, for example, instead of

```
str(self.lineEdit_2.text()).decode("utf-8")
```

you should write instead

```
unicode(self.lineEdit_2.text()).encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: i have tried to do what you say but i got the following error when i do it without `str()` function  `AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: @FRe34 Ah OK, what you're looking for, then, is the function `unicode()` instead of `str`. I'll edit my answer.