# Unicode codes of the greek alphabet in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am running this code in python 2.7 version.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0], 'lib'))
from bottle import route, run, static_file, request
import pymysql as db
import settings

con = db.connect(
    settings.mysql_host, 
    settings.mysql_user, 
    settings.mysql_passwd, 
    settings.mysql_schema,
    charset='utf8',
    use_unicode=True)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT tragoudi.titlos, tragoudi.etos_par, cd_production.etaireia FROM tragoudi JOIN singer_prod ON tragoudi.titlos=singer_prod.title JOIN cd_production ON singer_prod.cd=cd_production.code_cd GROUP BY tragoudi.titlos HAVING tragoudi.titlos LIKE %s AND tragoudi.etos_par LIKE %s AND cd_production.etaireia LIKE %s",("ΑΓΩΝΙΑ","1978","SONY"))
con.commit()

#cur.execute("SELECT * FROM kalitexnis")


for row in cur.fetchall():
    table = row[:]

print table
con.close()
```

and it gives me as a result this:

```
(u'\u0391\u0393\u03a9\u039d\u0399\u0391', 1978, u'SONY')
```

which is correct because the unicode of the word 'ΑΓΩΝΙΑ΄ is `A=\u0391`   `Γ=\u0393` etc.
So my question is that if there is a way when i `print table` to get as a result

```
(u'ΑΓΩΝΙΑ', 1978, u'SONY')
```

Comment: If you `print table[0]` it shows the characters correctly, also removing quotes and the `u`. Tuples show the `repr` of their elements. Do you really need exactly what you showed?

Comment: read this maybe that will help you
[How to convert Arabic text from PyQt4 to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220459/how-to-convert-arabic-text-from-pyqt4-to-utf-8?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 uses u as a prefix to tell it that it is a Unicode string, so if you print the list element by element, it should print out correctly.

So:

```
for x in table
    print x
```